# How to convert auto numbering list to plain text in PowerPoint 2013?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

I have PowerPoint slides with numbering lists (1, 1.1, 2, 3,...), and I need to quick method to convert this list to selectable numbers, keeping format (font size and indent).

Comment: No settings to directly convert it. You can remove the numbering by cut and pasted with text. Or right-click the numbering list, select None for numbering level.

Comment: Thanks WinniL, I think may be there's code can e run to make this job, I faces this issue in files with many many slides, means this solution will take a huge time. I hope I will find another solution, thanks alot.